# deduct height of text element using d3

Tags: d3.js

Since you can't wrap `<text>` elements with another graphical element, I'd though I'd just add a `rect` element on a similar coordinates to wrap the text in a rectangular border. However, I'd like to calculate the width and height of that rectangular according to that of the text (which changes). So, something like this:

```
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr({ ... });

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr({
        width: text.attr("width") + 5,
        height: text.attr("height") + 5
    });
```

Only that doesn't work. How can I grab the height and width of a text element (if at all)? I searched around Google and SO and didn't find any similar questions on the subject.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use .getBBox():

```
> text.node().getBBox()
SVGRect {height: 17, width: 56, y: -14, x: 0}

var rect = svg.append('rect')
    .attr(text.node().getBBox())
```